# Jquery Templates plugIn

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-templates

Hey guys, i'm trying this example from [Dave Ward blog](http://encosia.com/2010/11/10/composition-with-jquery-templates-why-and-how/)

about jQuery Templates and something i'm doing wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.
 Here's his code:
Data:

```
 var invoice = {
  invoiceItems: [
    { type: 'item', 
      part: '99Designs', description: '99 Designs Logo', 
      price: 450.00, qty: 1 },
    { type: 'service',
      service: 'Web development and testing', 
      price: 25000.00 },
    { type: 'item',
      part: 'LinodeMonthly', description: 'Monthly site hosting', 
      price: 40.00, qty: 12 }
  ]
};
```

Client:

```
  <script id="invoiceTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
      <table class="invoice">
      {{each lineItems}}
        {{tmpl($value) get_invoiceRowTemplateName(type)}}
      {{/each}}
      </table>
  </script>
```

Js:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#invoiceTemplate').tmpl(invoice).appendTo('body');
});

function get_invoiceRowTemplateName(type) {
  // Return a template selector that matches our 
  //  convention of <type>RowTemplate.
  return '#' + type + 'RowTemplate';
}
```

Comment: you might want to elaborate about what 'wrong' means... do you get an output, is the output wrong, what's wrong with the result, etc etc

Comment: @Ben
it wasn't doing anything, but Dave already answered my question i was missing "row" templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget the row templates:

```
<script id="serviceRowTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr class="service">
    <td colspan="2">${service}</td>
    <td colspan="2">${price}</td>
  </tr>
</script>

<script id="itemRowTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr class="item">
    <td>${item}</td>
    <td>${description}</td>
    <td>${price}</td>
    <td>${qty}</td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

When get_invoiceRowTemplateName() resolves each item's `type` to the corresponding *type*RowTemplate, those individual row templates are what is used to render each item.